Why is a resolution of portrait mode 480 x 640 described as 4 : 3 instead of 3 : 4?
As I've read that:

The aspect ratio of an image is the ratio of its width to its height. For instance, if a rectangle has an aspect ratio of 2:1, then it is twice as wide as it is tall. The aspect ratio formula is width divided by height: r = w / h.

Source: https://study.com/academy/lesson/aspect-ratio-definition-calculation.html (emphasis added)
If you divide 480 by 640, the result is 0.75, or 3 : 4.
Then why do I see it described as being a 4 : 3 aspect ratio in several places? (e.g. Android Camera, Google)
Would anyone be able to explain this please?
I need to find the exact aspect ratio to use in my JavaScript code for video camera input calculations.
So my code seems to be correct using 480 x 640 and 4 : 3, but when I switch to 3 : 4, it distorts the image. So I would like to understand the logic behind the Aspect Ratio Calculation.

Apparently the aspect ratio is calculated by longest side : shortest side, which is why the aspect ratio for 480 x 640 is 4 : 3.

the technical way to "Define" aspect ratio is with "longest side:shortest side"

Answer from Mathematics department: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4894222/1309146

There is 2 different ways to represent that. The first one is Landscape Orientation which larger number that comes first for display. The second one is Portrait Orientation which that the smaller number that comes first.
So in Landscape Orientation it will be shown 4:3 and in Portrait Orientation it will be 3:4.
Also, you want to use in JS so u need to use the mathematically correct aspect ratio which calculated by  Aspect ratio = Longest Side / Shortest Side so it will be 4:3.
It has been edited after getting clarify from @Z0q

Thank your for your answer. So my code seems to be correct using 480 x 640 and 4 : 3, but when I switch to 3 : 4, it distorts the image. That is why I asked the question. But I've understood now that aspect ratio is always calculated from it's longest side, regardless of orientation

@Z0q I have edited my answer to avoid any misunderstanding.
